# 2.9x Theme - Visual Chart?

Tags: theme

Is there a visual chart showing what colors connect to each UI element,
...besides trial and error?
[image]

Comment: I have never see one. It would pretty long though...

Comment: Looks like it's been requested. https://devtalk.blender.org/t/making-theme-creation-easier-less-daunting/13014

Comment: There are many request on the theme if  you dig into rightclickselect. Probably it would be more useful something like an eyedropper that open the options section for the selection. Something like https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Tsdbbc/ I think there are too many settings for an extensive listing.